# Secure inter-server communication with node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, communication

is there any example about secure inter-server communication in node.js?
Is socket.io necessary to realize this or I may use express too?
I would like to realize mutual authentication between two servers.

Thanks to all!!!

This is an example of what i've done; unfortunately it doesn't work...

Server 1

```
...
var ioc = require('socket.io-client');
var socketc = ioc.connect("https://127.0.0.1:5000", {'force new connection':true, 'secure':true});
...
```

Server 2

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var io = require('socket.io');
var crypto = require('crypto');

// path to private key and certificate
var pathSSH = 'C:\\cert\\';
//array containing private key and certificate
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(pathSSH + 'keySatellite.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(pathSSH + 'keySatellite-cert.pem')
};

var port = 5000;

var server = https.createServer(options, function(req, res) {
    console.log('Connection with satellite node');
});

var sio = io.listen(server);

// ...listening at port XXXXX
server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("HTTPS server listening on port " + port);
});

sio.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('connected');
    socket.disconnect();
});
```

**UPDATE 1**
I've noticed that server to server communication works fine if I set a http connection instead of https.

Comment: It seems like what you need is ssl (transport-layer security, not application level). That would work for socket.io, http (express), and others. Though it's hard to say for your as your question is rather vague.

Comment: added code example, I hope it's more clear now. Thanks